# Unparameterized Identity column in Vertica

Tags: sql, database, data-warehouse, vertica

If there is an `Identity` column in Vertica that has no parameters defined, how does it work ?

`CREATE MULTISET TABLE db.user_state
(
    active_user_state_key  IDENTITY ,
    load_key int NOT NULL
)`

For example in above code, where will the `Identity` column start from and increment by

Comment: Is the documentation unclear? http://my.vertica.com/docs/5.0/HTML/Master/4918.htm

Comment: I'll test it later, but as Pondlife mentions you can set the seed and increment. Also, I'm pretty sure "MULTISET" isn't a keyword in Vertica as a FYI.

Comment: @Pondlife Thanks the link was helpful.

Comment: @geoffrobinson Actually I was doing a code migration from Vertica to Teradata and since no seed/increment was mentioned with Identity in Vertica code I got confused. About Multiset, it's a Teradata keyword, I typed that accidently.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE db.user_state ( active_user_state_key IDENTITY (1,1) , load_key int NOT NULL );
```

Where the IDENTITY (1,1,100) is **start** from 1 , **increment** by one and **cache** max per sessions value will be 100 .
- the values must be positive. 
- the **start** value specifies the number at which to start the IDENTITY column. Default: 1.
- the **increment** value specifies how much to increment the value from the previous row's value. Default: 1.
- the third parameter **cache** -this parameter is optional and it states a unique number each node allocates per session.

But you can always use sequences.